# Why doesn't the "npm run dev" start my local host?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, npm, command-line, frontity

I am trying to host a local server of a Frontity project but for some reason the command `npm run dev` doesn't successfully host the project.

Here the command line output:
[image: command line output]

Here are my scripts from `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "frontity dev",
    "build": "frontity build",
    "serve": "frontity serve"
}
```

I tried looking at my npm packages but could not figure this out.

After running `npx frontity dev` I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVw1s.png)

Comment: Kindly share the 'scripts' tag under package.json for better understanding of the problem that you are facing

Comment: Here is my 'scripts tag':

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "frontity dev",
    "build": "frontity build",
    "serve": "frontity serve"
  }

Comment: Try running `npx frontity dev`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am getting error message from the command line

Comment: Which node version do you use ? Recommended is 14.7.0.